# ruby on rails how to deal with NaN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have read few posts regarding `NaN` but did not figure out how to deal with it in Ruby on Rails. I want to check a value if it is a `NaN` I want to replace it with Zero(0).
I tried the following

```
logger.info(".is_a? Fixnum #{percent.is_a? Fixnum}")
```

when percent has `NaN` it returns me false.

I have made few changes in the logger

```
logger.info("Fixnum #{percent.is_a? Fixnum} percent #{percent}")
```

Output

```
Fixnum false percent 94.44444444444444
Fixnum false percent NaN
Fixnum false percent 87.0
```

Answer (score 112, accepted):

`NaN` is instance of `Float`. Use [`Float#nan?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Float.html#method-i-nan-3F) method.

```
>> nan = 0.0/0 # OR nan = Float::NAN
=> NaN
>> nan.class
=> Float
>> nan.nan?
=> true
>> nan.is_a?(Float) && nan.nan?
=> true
>> (nan.is_a?(Float) && nan.nan?) ? 0 : nan
=> 0
```

**UPDATE**

[`NaN` could also be an instance of `BigDecimal`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#NAN):

```
((nan.is_a?(Float) || nan.is_a?(BigDecimal)) && nan.nan?) ? 0 : nan
```

or

```
{Float::NAN => 0, BigDecimal::NAN => 0}.fetch(nan, nan)
```

Comment: It's also defined as a constant: `Float::NAN #=> Nan`

Comment: If you are working with the standard library, `NaN` could also be an instance of `BigDecimal`.

Comment: @cornflakes24, Thank you for the comment. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by @falsetru was helpful, but you should be careful using their last suggestion:

```rb
{Float::NAN => 0, BigDecimal::NAN => 0}.fetch(nan, nan)
```

Using ruby version 2.5, if I use the example they provided in `irb`:

```rb
>> require "bigdecimal"
=> true
>> nan = 0.0/0 # OR nan = Float::NAN
=> NaN
>> {Float::NAN => 0, BigDecimal::NAN => 0}.fetch(nan, nan)
=> NaN
```

You get `NaN` instead of the expected `0`. I would use their previous suggestion instead:

```rb
((nan.is_a?(Float) || nan.is_a?(BigDecimal)) && nan.nan?) ? 0 : nan
```

```rb
>> require "bigdecimal"
=> true
>> nan = 0.0/0 # OR nan = Float::NAN
=> NaN
>> ((nan.is_a?(Float) || nan.is_a?(BigDecimal)) && nan.nan?) ? 0 : nan
=> 0
```