# Ruby on Rails - find where value equals NaN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

How should I write a query to find records where a value is NaN?

```rb
> Person.where(age: NaN)
NameError: uninitialized constant NaN
```

Comment: maybe it can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154461/ruby-on-rails-how-to-deal-with-nan

Comment: What is the type of the `age` column in your database?

Answer (score 5):

You should do:

```
Person.where(age: Float::NAN)
```

Check this [NAN](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Float.html#NAN) .

Answer (score 1):

If you don't necessarily need to get a AR collection as a result of selection, but will be ok with an array, you can do it like this:

```
Person.all.select{ |p| p.age.nan? }
```

Comment: Are you sure? I get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'find_all' for #<Class:0x007fe91b9aa540>`

Comment: @OllieGlass edited the answer (mixed up with Ruby's `find_all`)