# Check if number is NaN

Tags: ruby, nan

I'm trying to check if a variable I have is equals to NaN in my Ruby on Rails application.

I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154461/ruby-on-rails-how-to-deal-with-nan), but it's not really useful because in my code I want to return 0 if the variable is NaN and the value otherwise:

```
 return (average.nan ? 0 : average.round(1))
```

The problem is that if the number is not a NaN I get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `nan?' for 10:Fixnum
```

I can't check if the number is a Float instance because it is in both cases (probably, I'm calculating an average).
What can I do? 
It is strange only to me that a function to check if a variable is equals to NaN is avaible only to NaN objects?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235863/test-if-a-string-is-basically-an-integer-in-quotes-using-ruby) may be your answer.

Comment: are you looking for average.nil?

Comment: @nikkypx for nil check this would need to be done `average.to_i.nil?`

Comment: @AAnkudovich no, you can call nil on any object, to_i on a nil object would be 0, so your example would be 0.nil?

Comment: i see your point sorry

Comment: What about ``return average.round(1) rescue 0``

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Quickest way is to use this:

```
under_the_test.to_f.nan? # gives you true/false e.g.:
123.to_f.nan? # => false
(123/0.0).to_f.nan? #=> true
```

Also note that only Floats have `#nan?` method defined on them, that's the reason why I'm using `#to_f` in order to convert result to float first.

Tip: if you have integer calculation that potentially can divide by zero this will not work:

```
(123/0).to_f.nan?
```

Because both 123 and 0 are integers and that will throw `ZeroDivisionError`, in order to overcome that issue `Float::NAN` constant can be useful - for example like this:

```
return Float::NAN if divisor == 0
return x / divisor
```

Comment: This solved my problem but in my console, this: (123/0.0).to_f.nan? equals false

Ruby:  2.2.3p173
Rails: 4.2.5.1

Comment: Your division by zero example == NaN example is bad practice. According to standards defined by `IEEE754`: `0.0 / 0 == Float::NAN` and `1.0/0 == Float::INFINITY`. But ruby already complies to the standard, so there is no need to hand-craft your own `return` statements.

Comment: Downvoted because the code is incorrect--currently in Ruby, dividing an `Integer` by a`Float` such as in `(123/0.0)` will result in a `Float::INFINITY`, ***NOT*** `Float::NAN` which is what the question asked about.

Answer (score 2):

I found this answer while duckducking for something that is neither `NaN` nor `Infinity` (e.g., a finite number). Hence I'll add my discovery here for next googlers.

And as always in ruby, the answer was just to type my expectation while searching in the `Float` documentation, and find [`finite?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.3/Float.html#method-i-finite-3F)

```rb
n = 1/0.0 #=> Infinity
n.nan? #=> false
n.finite? #=> false
```

Comment: It works fine only for NaN.
Suppose you have to check a variable which can either be number or NaN,
In this case for example a `valid_number.nan?` throws error. So as per @river 's answer it's best to add `.to_f` before checkin `.nan?`

Answer (score 1):

The best way to avoid this kind of problem is to rely on the fact that a NaN isn't even equal to itself:

```
a = 0.0/0.0
a != a
# -> True !
```

This is likely not going to be an issue with any other type.